# Validate on submit button got issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Here is my code example

```
<form action="next2.php" method="post" name="next2" id="next2" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
```

Below is my function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm()
    {
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
       return false;
    }
</script>
```

On press, the form still submit, but if i change

```
onsubmit="return false;"
```

then the form won't submit, how do I use the function to return false as i need do some if else validation

Comment: rename your function, call it `submitForm`

Comment: @vol7ron same issue, form still get posted.

Comment: @BUN there might be something else going on your function resulting in a JavaScript error, if it is still submitting (it's not getting to the return false)

Comment: try declaring your script tag inside the head, before the body, may be the function is unknown at the time you're calling it. Use the debug utility in your google browser to investigate further

Comment: @vol7ron, If i type in this line before return false, it will not stop the form for submit -    var name = document.getElementById("name").value; [there is no console error]

Comment: Is there an element on your page called `name`?

Comment: i saw that tag was close wrongly, issue fixed. thanks

Comment: @BUN show that in your HTML above.  Make sure your `<input>` has the ID set correctly `id="name"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitForm() {
    return false;
  }
</script>

<form 
   action="next2.php" 
   method="post" 
   name="next2" 
   id="next2" 
   onsubmit="return submitForm();"
 >
```

`submit` is already a function for the form, you should call your JavaScript function something different, for instance `submitForm` as in the above.

Comment: if I type this line before return false, there is issue  var name = document.getElementById("name").value;    [there is no console error]

Comment: @BUN Which browser are you using? Make sure that you have an input element on the page with id of name. `<input id="name" type="text" />` and make sure no other elements also have `id="name"` (an ID can only appear once on the page)

Answer (score 0):

just remove the semicolon in your function and place a alert in your function to make sure whether the function is called first.and then try to add validation

Answer (score 0):

I like to make an invisible button for the actual submit which is only triggered after form validation:

```js
function validate() {
    var valid = true;
    $.each($('input'), function(){
        valid = valid && $(this).val().length > 0;
    })
    if (valid) {
        $('#realSubmit').click();
    } else {
        alert('Please fill out all fields!');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="next2.php" method="post" name="next2" id="next2" onsubmit="return submit();">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" />
    <button type="button" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit" id="realSubmit" style="display:none"></button>
</form>
```